# JQuery reverts to original CSS after keyup

Tags: jquery, css, keyup

I have the following function:

```
function setDropLinkFocus(divID){
    $("#" + divID).css("font-weight", "Bold");
}
```

which fires on both a keyup event and a mouseover event. On mouseover, it excutes fine, but on a keyup event, it executes, but then reverts back to the original css after about a second.  Using the element inspector, I can see that the css is also added, and then quickly removed. I've tried handling the keyup with:

```
$(this).keyup(function)
```

and:

```
$(this).live('keyup',function)
```

EDIT: 
I found the problem.  This was happening because the keyup event was also calling an AJAX autocomplete-dropdown function (which I didn't add to JSFiddle). So, the elements weren't being reverted, rather, they were being refreshed from the AJAX call. I changed it so the AJAX function isn't called upon the specific key code that I need.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to this in action ?

Comment: look at your keyup event, maybe is it refreshing or posting the page?

Comment: Does it revert back with mouseover as well when you mouse out of the element?  There's no reason it should be reverting back on keyup.  Once you set something in an event it stays unless you set it to something else, it doesn't revert back after the event is finished.  Are you sure you don't have another keyup event or something called somewhere that's changing it back?  Please setup a [jsfiddle.net](www.jsfiddle.net) demo of the problem.

Comment: You could try adding: event.preventDefault()

Comment: @DidierG. Thank you!  I've never used jsfiddle before, and was able to find the solution thanks to it.

Comment: @LostMohican Thanks for the tip!  My page wasn't being refreshed, but the elements were being generated by AJAX calls, so they were.

Comment: @user1071532, if you've solved your own problem you are allowed to post it as an answer and accept it.